# Opening a file gives unexpected return value

Tags: c, file, file-io, errno

could someone please explain me, why file opening is not successful? why printing "file" will give -1? Is it a problem with `char *source`?

```
int opf(char *source){
    int file;
    file=open(source,O_RWR);
    printf("%d",file); 
}
```

And is it possible to do something like this:
file is in another directory, so

```
int opf(char *source){
    int file;
    file=open("some_directory/ %s",source,O_RWR);
    printf("%d",file); 
}
```

here I get the "makes integer from pointer without a cast" error. I tried many different things but i guess the problem lies with me not grasping  correctly the concepts.

Comment: What is `O_RWR? Do you mean `O_RDWR?

Comment: As for your second and unrelated question (you should really post two questions) search for and read about `snprintf`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with pointers; you're trying to use `open` as if it were `printf`. But it's not `printf`. It's `open`.

Comment: You can't make things up and expect them to work or even expect to get a useful error message when you try them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open) of `open()` (*emphasis mine*)

> Upon successful completion, the function shall open the file and return a non-negative integer representing the lowest numbered unused file descriptor. **Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and errno set to indicate the error. No files shall be created or modified if the function returns -1.**

So, in your case, the `open()` has failed. Check for the `errno` to get more details on that. All the possible values for `errno` is also documented in the linked page.

That being said,

1. `O_RWR` does not seem to be a valid *mode*,`O_RDWR` is.
2. For the second approach, you can use [`sprintf()`/`snprintf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sprintf) first to create the `path` string and then you can pass that to `open()`.